# torrents not working on either Windows or Linux

Tags: bittorrent

I'm dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 7. I try downloading a torrent, but all it says is "downloading metadata" (or something of the sort) and the download never actually begins. Sorry about the brief details, but that's really all there is to it. What could be the issue?

Comment: Its not a rule but if you ever find yourself in this dilemma of Torrent not connecting/ISP blocking/no seeds/peers, then try downloading some very famous torrents to check. I always try downloading Ubuntu (latest version) as a starting point of troubleshooting. You can find other ones here.  http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Comment: Anything in the configuration of your firewall, including your router?

Answer (score 1):

Its possible your ISP is blocking torrents.  Check this page to [test](http://broadband.mpi-sws.org/transparency/glasnost.php).

Answer (score 0):

Hanging "downloading metadata" happens on magnet links and is because there might not be a lot of peers/seeders for the torrent in question, peers you need to get the full torrent file with all the hashes and file name data.

To make it easier, try searching on google for the hash of the magnet link and see if you can get the full torrent file from a mirror site. Some sites like zoink even use the hash as filename so it's very easy to get a copy.

Comment: "Also you have a typo" - You can and are encouraged to edit the question to fix obvious errors.

Comment: Will do next time.